# server mail logs too large

Tags: email, ubuntu, logging, postfix-mta

I have a ubuntu server which handles mail via postfix. The server has recently been caned by spam emails and the mail logs are really large as a consequence. The logs are stored with timestamps and I was just wondering if I can just clear out the old logs without consequence to recover some disk space?

Also, being none-too-clever about such things, I am struggling to see where to change the settings for log rotation and deletion... any clues from more knowledgable folks?

Comment: Voted to move this over to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). (Once/If 4 other people vote for this, it will automatically get moved over there, just so you are aware).

Answer (score 3):

Is this a question for serverfault.com ? If not, try `logrotate`.

According to `man logrotate`:

```
logrotate  is  designed  to ease administration of systems that generate large
numbers of log files. It allows automatic rotation, compression, removal, and
mailing of log files. Each log file may be handled daily, weekly, monthly, or
when it grows too large.
```

Comment: +1 for logrotate.  I'd give another +1 for requesting the move, but I'm not allowed. ;)

Comment: hadn't heard of serverfault.com - sorry if this is the wrong place! I'll try there. Cheers.